# Solving asymptotic notation based on a given constant

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

How does one show that $(n + b)^2 = Θ(n^2)$ is for any real constant b?

Comment: While the given answer is sufficient, one must also know that $f(n)$ is asymptotic to the highest power of $n$. This is because as $n$ becomes very large, the terms with smaller power of $n$ become insignificant. In your case, let $f(n) = (n + b)^2 = n^2 + 2nb + b^2$. Since the highest degree of $n$ is $2$, we say that $f(n)$ is asymptotic to $n^2$ (compare $n^2$ with $2nb$ for large values of $n$, e.g., $n = 100$). Since the value of the constant never changes, it does not affect the asymptotic equivalence of $f(n)$ because $n$ _will_ become larger than the constant at some point.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to note that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(n+b)^2}{n^2}$ is finite and non-zero.  In particular, we find that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(n+b)^2}{n^2} = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's reduce the equation:

$(n + b)^2 = n^2 + 2nb + b^2$

We observe that $n^2$ is the biggest term that grows faster than the other two terms. We also observe that this term is a tight bound by looking at its growth compared to the equation. Therefore, the asymptotic complexity of this equation is $\Theta(n^2)$.